# Jquery .click event on .fadeToggle with animated text only firing once

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get this click event to trigger each time ".expander" div is clicked.  It works once then just stops working.  Not really sure what do to from here.

The jquery is also set up to auto scroll the content in the ".expander" div and it does this. It also 
stops scrolling on click or on scroll from the mouse like it should.

But anyway I can't seem to figure out how to get the click event to fire more then once.  So it doesn't really toggle like it should.

Thanks in Advance!!

-Jackson

The HTML

```
<div class="resume group">
        <div class="group">
            <img src="images/">
            <div>
                <h1>Achievements</h1>
                <ul>
                <li>content</li>
                <li>content</li>
                <li>content</li>
                <li>content</li>
                </ul>
            <h2>Read my resume <a href="#" class="expander">here!</a></h2>
            </div>
            .</div>

        <div id="full-resume" class="content">
            <p> a bunch of content goes here.</p>
         </div>
```

Jquery

```
        $("#full-resume").hide();



        $(".expander").click(function () {
            $("#full-resume").fadeToggle("slow");
            $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".expander").offset().top -160 }, 450);
             $("#full-resume").animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 80000, 'linear');

            $("#full-resume").click(function (){
                $(this).stop();})


           $("#full-resume").bind("mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function(){
                          $('#full-resume').stop();
                         });

            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
```

Here is a jsfiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/jacksonvoice/Br9C3/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. you are binding the click event inside another click event, and this is useless. You are already binding multiple events to #full-resume, so you could remove the click event, since it is redundant with the mousedown
2. there must be a conflict between the toggleFade animation and the autoscroll. To prevent it, you must stop the autoscroll before firing the fade, like this:

> ```
> $(".expander").click(function () {
>     $("#full-resume").stop();
>     $("#full-resume").fadeToggle("slow");
> ```

Here is [the working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Br9C3/4/)

Comment: That did it, Thank you so much. Never would have figured that one out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared any variable called "event". You want to get it as an parameter but you don't. So I guess your line

```
event.preventDefault();
```

fails and your browser stops evaluating JS-code. Try to fix it and let us know about it. This should work:

```
$(".expander").click(function (event) {
```

EDIT: After this to your second problem (where you can't fade-in your div more than once). You have to stop any animation on your DIV (scrolling!) directly before hiding/showing it. This line at the very beginning of your clickhandler made it work for me:

```
$('.expander').click(function(event) {
    $('#full-resume').stop();
    //...existing function-body...
});
```

To look a bit ahead you should simply know if you're hiding or showing your container when entering the method. In each case you should do different things (not animating the scroll when hiding, etc.). The eventhandlers should be attached outfide of any other handler anyway.

Comment: Ok, so I passed **event** into the function like you showed.  Now it will let me close the #full-resume div by clicking .expander, but only if I place my mouse cursor in the #full-resume div and scroll up and down first.  However, once I close the div, clicking on .expander does nothing and I have to reload the page for it to work again.  So, I'm still stuck.  =(

Comment: A made a jsfiddle for this if it helps!  http://jsfiddle.net/jacksonvoice/Br9C3/3/

Comment: The fiddle did help a lot. My guess is, that your animations are at the wrong position. Showing it it shows and begins to scroll. But hiding it it also begins to scroll immediately! That's not necessarily bad, but your scrolling makes a conflict with fading in/out! See my edit for an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event parameter in the function and remove return false.

Comment: Ok so I passed **event** into the function like you said and individumm showed above and I also removed return false.  But It's still not working as I cannot toggle the #full-resume div.  Here is a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/jacksonvoice/Br9C3/3/    Thank you for the help!